# Spring Boot can not setup cache

Tags: java, spring, maven, caching, spring-boot

Try to setup Memcache in Spring Boot project, but it does not work. I even try to setup default cache(ConcurrentMapCacheManager), but it does not work as well.

Every tutorial that I read(even Spring official) say that this configuration is enought to setup cache

cache configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("test_cache");
    }

}
```

Cache using:

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "test_cache")
public class UserServiceImpl extends IUserService {
  ...
    @Cacheable
    public UserEntity getByEmail(String email) {
        UserEntity entity = repository.findByEmail(email);

        return entity;
    }
...
}
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Is it possible that some of the dependency conflict with spring cache dependency?

Comment: can you elaborate on 'it does not work'? Is there an exception?

Comment: @RobertFarley, method getByEmail for same email param executes each time, but it should cache the result after first time

Comment: Method `getByEmail` is called from another bean, eg. from a Controller?

Comment: @Izagkaretos, yes, method called from another bean

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Memcached your **UserEntity** should be **serialized** (i.e. *UserEntity implements Serializable*).

You can check a small sample project of using Spring Boot with Memcached [here](https://github.com/sixhours-team/spring-boot-memcached-demo-java).

Answer (score 1):

I just created a demo project to demonstrate how this simple Cache Configuration is working.

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager("test_cache");
    }
}
```

The interface for the Service.

```
public interface TestDataService {
    String getEmail(String email);
}
```

The corresponding implementation.

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames={"test_cache"})
public class TestDataServiceImpl implements TestDataService {

    @Cacheable
    public String getEmail(String email) {
        return email;
    }
}
```

And a dummy Controller.

```
@RestController
public class TestDataController {

    private TestDataService testDataService;

    @Autowired
    public TestDataController(TestDataService testDataService) {
        this.testDataService = testDataService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "test")
    String getEmail() {
        return testDataService.getEmail("test.me");
    }
}
```

Then, when you call http request `localhost:8080/test` and you put a breakpoint into `TestDataServiceImpl.getEmail()` you can see that only the first time the method is actually being executed.

I have added code in [github](https://github.com/lzagkaretos/cache-demo) in order to take a look if you wish.